# jquery function like toggle and on second click show initial content

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using jquery and I'm facing a problem. I would like to use a function that acts like toggle but without using it, and that allows to show initial content on second click. 
I have differents "link" that when you click on, it shows different content.

```
<div class="tabs">
    <a id="clicker" onclick="showContent(1)">click me 1</a>
    <a id="clicker2" onclick="showContent(2)">click me 2</a>
    <a id="clicker3" onclick="showContent(3)">click me 3</a>
</div>
```

Here are the contents:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="initial">hello here is initial content</div>
    <div class="show_this">show/hide</div>
    <div class="show_this_2">show/hide2</div>
    <div class="show_this_3">show/hide3</div>
</div>
```

So when I click on clicker I show `.show_this` content. When I click on clicker2 I show `.show_this_2` content ... And when i do a second click on the link I would like to show the content of class initial.

I managed to show the content of each tabs, and on second click show the initial content. But my problem is that I would like that when I show the content of a tab I don't have to do two clicks to show the content of another tab. It always show first the initial content before showing the content of the tab I need.
When I click on "click me 1" and directly after "click me 2", it doesn't show me "show/hide2" but "hello here is initial content" first. So I have to click again on "click me 2" to show what I want. How to avoid this ?

I did a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruGvV/111/) and snippet to be more explicit.

```js
$(".show_this").hide();   
$(".show_this_2").hide();   
$(".show_this_3").hide();

showContent();
   
function showContent(number){
    var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
    
    if (clicks) {
        if (number == 1) {
            $(".show_this").show();
          $(".show_this_2").hide();
           $(".show_this_3").hide();
          $(".initial").hide();
        } else if (number == 2) {
           $(".show_this_2").show();
         $(".show_this").hide();
          $(".show_this_3").hide();
          $(".initial").hide();
        } else if (number == 3) {
            $(".show_this_3").show();
         $(".show_this").hide();
          $(".show_this_2").hide();
           $(".initial").hide();
        }
    } else {
       $(".initial").show();
      $(".show_this").hide();   
      $(".show_this_2").hide();   
      $(".show_this_3").hide();  
    }
    
    $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
}

window.showContent = showContent;
```

```css
.initial{
  color: white;
}
#clicker, .show_this{
  color: red;
}
#clicker2, .show_this_2{
  color: green;
}
#clicker3, .show_this_3{
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <div class="initial">hello here is initial content</div>
    <div class="show_this">show/hide</div>
    <div class="show_this_2">show/hide2</div>
    <div class="show_this_3">show/hide3</div>
</div>
<div class="tabs">
    <a id="clicker" onclick="showContent(1)">click me 1</a>
    <a id="clicker2" onclick="showContent(2)">click me 2</a>
    <a id="clicker3" onclick="showContent(3)">click me 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to do. Do you mean that 'hello here is initial content' should be the default shown, then clicking `show_this_X` should toggle the content related to those elements?

Comment: Yes, when you first click on a "click me x" it has to show its content, when you second click on it it has to show "hello here is initial content". But here the first click on "click me x" doesn't show immediately the content, it always go through first "hello here is initial content". (except at the really begginning)

Comment: Got it. I added an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you want the default text to show and the toggles to override that you can simply check if no `show_this_X` element is displayed and replace the default text.

Also note that you should use unobtrusive methods to attach your event handlers, not inline event handlers. Also, you can use common classes to group your elements, which helps to simplify both the JS and the CSS styling. Something like this:

```js
$('.clicker').click(function() {
  var $target = $($(this).data('target')).toggle();
  $('.show_this').not($target).hide();
  $('.initial').toggle(!$target.is(':visible'));
  
  $('.clicker').not(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
body, html { background-color: #333; }
.initial { color: white; }
.show_this { display: none; }
#show1, #click1 { color: red; }
#show2, #click2 { color: green; }
#show3, #click3 { color: yellow; }
#clicker-container .clicker.active { color: purple !important }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="initial">hello here is initial content</div>
  <div id="show1" class="show_this">show/hide</div>
  <div id="show2" class="show_this">show/hide2</div>
  <div id="show3" class="show_this">show/hide3</div>
</div>
<div class="tabs" id="clicker-container">
  <a id="click1" class="clicker" data-target="#show1">click me 1</a>
  <a id="click2" class="clicker" data-target="#show2">click me 2</a>
  <a id="click3" class="clicker" data-target="#show3">click me 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's the result I expected. But I have to change everything I did, and inline event handlers helps me. (I have more things to add, I just simplified here)

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped. I'd strongly suggest you don't use inline handlers though, even if it means having to refactor your code. They are very antiquated and considered bad practice.

Comment: I can't upvote your post. :( Would you also know how to do same logic with active tab ? Like when you click on "clickme1" it becomes purple, when you click again on it becomes at its initial color, and when you click on "clickme2" while "clickme1" is  active it removes active class in clickme1 and add class active in "clickme2".

Comment: I tried to use "$(this).toggleClass("active")". It removes the active class on second click but not when I'm clicking on other tab. (result => both are active). Like this https://jsfiddle.net/csak9k4q/1/. I don't want both becoming blue when you click on other square, but only on the one you just clicked.

Comment: I updated the answer for you. You need to remove the class from the other clickable elements too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the content is displayed instead of clicks to check if current item is displayed. There sometimes bugs with `:visibilty` in Chrome
In your case you could use

```
if ($(this).css('display') !== 'none')
```